# Gitflow: Merging hotfix branch to develop carries merge commits made to master

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm on a project that's (sort of) following gitflow. It has a `master` and `develop` branch and it's had some releases already (these were done from `develop` to `master` because we were doing it wrong, but I don't think it changes the question).

Now there's a hotfix we need to make. We create a `hotfix-x` branch off of `master`, bump the version, make the change, and merge it to `master`. Now we try and merge the `hotfix-x` branch back to `develop`. But because the `hotfix-x` branch was created off of `master`, it includes all the merge commits from `develop` to `master`.

We don't want those merge commits in `develop`, do we? How do we handle this?

Comment: What are you trying to avoid ? A cluttered history? Because other than that (and even then, arguably inconsequential), I don't see what "problems" can arise with your description of events.

Comment: Yeah there aren't any "problems". We just assumed it was wrong to see merge commits from `develop` to `master` back in `develop`. We were wondering if we were missing something or if this is just what gitflow projects are supposed to look like. Didn't seem to be called out in any of the articles I found. Those always showed `hotfix`, `master`, and `develop` branching off from the same commit.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments, this is just an expected result of gitflow so I'll go ahead and close this.